# Scala/Akka: Run code after an actor doesn't receive a message for a given timeout

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that receives messages in bunches--that is, it typically receives several messages in rapid succession, followed by long periods of inactivity. I would like to execute code when the actor hasn't received a message for, say, 250ms.

Just to clarify what I mean, in Javascript, I might write a bit of code like this:

```
function gotMessage() {
  if(this.idleTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(this.idleTimeout);
  }

  this.idleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    //My code here
  }, 250);
}
```

How might I achieve that effect in Scala, or in Akka if there's a mechanism for it already in that library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That functionality is described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Receive_timeout) (Akka actors documentation page, "Receive timeout" section).

The `setReceiveTimeout` method has documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorContext)

Comment: Though beware that receiveTimeout works for all messages. i.e. say receiveTimeout = 100 msec, actor sent a message to actor `A` and and `B`. If any of `A` or `B` replies back on `<100 msec`, receiveTimeout will not be triggered. If you want per actor basis i.e. you want to know if `A` does not replies in 100 sec, and `B` does not replies in 100 sec or so. Then you need to write your own code to do it. Is this @Ben what you want?